# Cannot convert Int32 to null when trying to add a row to table

Tags: c#, sql-server, ef-core-2.2

I'm trying to add a row to a table that has a foreign key pointing towards another location in the same table. This foreign key is defined as nullable.
When trying to add an entry to the table, I am getting the error

```
"errors": {
    "parentId": [
      "Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Int32'. Path 'parentId', line 4, position 18."
    ]
  },
```

If I try to pass a random int, I get `The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint`, which makes sense, since there are no other entries in the table.
[image: nullable]

As you can see, the foreign key is seen as nullable.

I've tried not passing the field at all, not passing any parameters in when passing the field, passing null, all of which generated the later error, with the exception of when I tried passing null, which gave me the converting error.

I am using swagger ui to pass the JSON.

Class in question:

```cs
public class 
{
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
    public Company Parent { get; set; }     
}
```

I would like to create the first row on this table and set it's foreign key to null.

After implementing the fixes suggested in the answers, my error turned from a conversion error to the foreign constraint error stated above, even when passing a null.

Code, as per request:

DbContext:

```
public class ArtGalleriesContext:DbContext
{
    public ArtGalleriesContext(DbContextOptions<ArtGalleriesContext> options):base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<ArtItem> ArtItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Floor> Floors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserLocation> UserLocations { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserLocation>()
            .HasKey(u => new {u.UserId, u.LocationId});
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(
                "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=GalleriesDB;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost("Companies")]
public IActionResult CreateCompany([FromBody]CreateCompanyRequest createCompanyRequest)
{
    try
    {
        if (createCompanyRequest==null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return CreatedAtRoute("CompanyById", _repository.Company.CreateCompany(createCompanyRequest),
            createCompanyRequest);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, e.InnerException);
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public int CreateCompany(CreateCompanyRequest createCompanyRequest)
{
    Company company = new Company()
    {
        CountryId = createCompanyRequest.CountryId,
        Name = createCompanyRequest.Name,
        ParentId = createCompanyRequest.ParentId
    };
    _context.Companies.Add(company);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return company.Id;
}
```

Possibly related info: I tried populating the table using Microsoft SQL Server Manager. It was successful, however, this is the result:

[image: weird id]

There is clearly something wrong, since it started adding entried starting with PK 14.

After further inspection, I noticed that even if adding a row to the table fails, the primary key still increments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is at the deserialization of the json to model, you have two options here:

1. Add to your startup.cs class Json options to ignore null values like so:

   ```
   .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
    });
   ```
2. Set on the property itself to ignore null values so it will initialize that `int?` as null

   ```
   public class 
   {
      public Country Country { get; set; }
      [Required]
      public int CountryId { get; set; }
      [Required]
      public int Id { get; set; }
      [Required]
      public string Name { get; set; }
      [JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
      public int? ParentId { get; set; }
      [ForeignKey("ParentId")]
      public Company Parent { get; set; }     
   }
   ```

Comment: Yes, friend. This seems to have helped. I've added JsonOptions to my startup. Still, new problems were encountered. Now, when I try passing `"parentId":null`, I get `The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint`

Comment: @NAlexP Add to your question your database context model builder and the insert code method.

Comment: Edited as per request.

Comment: @NAlexP Try running dotnet ef migrations add to check whether or not EF detect any changes in your models, and if your Migrations table matches all the migrations existing in your Migrations folder

Comment: I'm using vs powershell. Are you suggesting I do an `add-migration` command and to check my migration.cs?

Comment: @NAlexP Yes that command and check your migrations folder if the created one has any alterations

Comment: No modifications were picked up. The weirdest thing is that now it works, using the method generate a 500 response but writes data to the database. I'll open another question for this issue. Thanks a lot for the help, friend.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your use case, you may also want to consider having the [JSON Serializer ignore nulls](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_NullValueHandling.htm)

Or use "JsonProperty" attribute:

```
[JsonProperty(NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public int? ParentId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be solved by both above answers, but also, I noticed that I only declared `ParentId` as nullable int in my entity class, not in my model, `CreateCompanyRequest`; changing it's type inside the model solved the issue.

The conversion issue was because I tried passing a null value inside the model class, which contained an int prop, not a nullable int prop.